# access permission in linux

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I m running linux on my android phone using gnuroot debian.I had installed gcc compiler.I had 
make a c program on linux and compiled it with
command
g++ helloworld.c -o helloworld

I got helloworld file within the same directory and executing it with command
./helloworld
I got message "bash : ./hello world:  Permission denied"
then I use chmod u+x helloworld
then I again execute it with same above command again I got same message permission denied
then I use command for changing the permission 
sudo chmod u+x helloworld
Then I again got the same message permission denied 
when I m listing the file after using chmod 
I got there is no change in permission 
Plz help I will be very grateful to you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android mounts `/storage/emulated` with the `noexec` parameter, which means that files there can't be executed regardless of permissions. You need to put your binary somewhere not under there (and not under somewhere that's just a symlink to there).

Comment: I understand you answer,but is there any  way to mount  exec parameter on emaluated

Comment: Not unless your phone is rooted. If it is, you can do `mount -o remount,exec /storage/emulated`, but that's not good from a security standpoint. A better alternative is to put it somewhere like the terminal app's data directory.